# Two different font-family in one sentence?

Tags: fonts, font-family

How can I use two different font-family in one sentence?

Like this for example:

Seller: **apple, pear, cucumber**

I have tried to do following:

```
<p><span>Seller:</span> </p> <h5> apple, pear, cucumber</h5> 

.p {
  //text-align: left;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'PoppinsLight', sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.5s; 
   
}
 
.h5{
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   margin-top: 5px;
   font-family: 'PoppinsMedium';
   font-style: normal;
   font-size: 17px;
}
```

but its not working.it results in a new paragraph

Comment: You mean "it Results in a new paragraph" yes. it definitely because you are using **h5** tag within **p** tag. **h5** tag make line breaks.

Comment: First you need to change code as follows, then your new line issue will not caused
<p><span>Seller:</span> apple, pear, cucumber</p>

Answer (score 0):

This issue can happen due to overriding the styles. anyway, you can try following code,

```
.p {
  //text-align: left;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'PoppinsLight', sans-serif !important;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.5s; 
   
}
```

```
.h5{
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   margin-top: 5px;
   font-family: 'PoppinsMedium' !important;
   font-style: normal;
   font-size: 17px;
}
```

In here **!important** is given the priority to this style.

Comment: this answer for how to give some priority to some styles if it is overridden by another style.